# If Zeno could drive: Traveling at a speed (in miles per hour) that always exactly matches the distance (in miles) to the destination

Tags: harmonic-numbers

As I was driving on the highway this afternoon, I thought to myself: what if, at each moment, I were to move at a speed that matched exactly the distance I had remaining? As an example, at 60 miles from the destination I would drive at 60 miles per hour; then, with 59 miles remaining, I would slow to 59 miles per hour; and so on, of course with infinitesimal precision. Two questions emerge from this situation:

1. How long will it take to travel from mile-marker 60 to mile-marker 0?
2. And how long will it take to travel from mile-marker 60 to, say, mile-marker 20?

I've read through several previous postings of this same question ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659183/driving-and-time-problem) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245720/how-long-til-we-get-there-road-trip-puzzle), for example) but have yet to find a satisfying, thorough explanation. (How exactly, for example, do we involve the harmonic number $H_{60}$ to this problem?)

Comment: This isn't an infinite series it is just a sum $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{60-i}$ where $n=60-m$ where m is the mile marker you stop at.

Comment: @senreigh but they said infinitesimal precision. I take that to mean integrate.

Comment: This is discrete though once you get to 1 you go 1 mile per hour for 1 hour then stop so it doesn't involve an integral, if you were continuously slowing down however then the integral  $\int_0^{60} \frac{1}{60-x}dx$ diverges. but if you stop at say 20 then its fine $\int_{20}^{60} \frac{1}{60-x}dx$.

Comment: Can OP clarify whether they mean discrete or continuous?

Comment: I think both are interesting cases to consider, actually, so I appreciate both of the solutions posted here. Initially, though, I was taking deceleration to be continuous.

Answer (score 5):

Your velocity is $v(t)=60-x(t)$ where $x(t)$ is the distance from start. Note that $v(t)=x'(t)$ so this is $x'(t)=60-x(t)$. Solution to this differential equation is $x(t)=60+Ce^{-t}$. Note that $x(0)=0$ and so $x(t)=60-60e^{-t}$. Note that for all finite time $t$ we have $x(t)<60$ (i.e. you aren't at your desination). However $\lim_{t\to\infty} x(t)=60$.